# .htaccess at any length

Tags: regex, .htaccess

What would be the valid .htaccess rules for doing something like this

```
/mypage/ --> /index.php?page=mypage
/mypage/param1/value1/ -->index.php?page=mypage&params=param1/value1
```

With an potentially unlimited number of parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best is to to pass the entire part after the /mypage/ as an param to the php script and have that decode it:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/(.*) index.php?page=mypage&params=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also if you want page to be dynamic:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&params=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)(/(.*))? index.php?page=$1&params=$3 [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT**
Added Cal's suggestion, thanks Cal.

**Edit**
If I understand your comment correctly: (if not please explain). You can just use a switch statement with a default action which is the same as the index action for the page variable:

```
switch($_GET['page']){
 case 'mypage':
  doMyPageStuff();
 break;
 case 'foo':
  doFooStuff();
 break;
 case 'index':
 default:
  doIndexStuff();
 break;
}
```

Comment: The second method is what I need more of but how do I ignore the / after mypage?

Comment: what do you mean by ignore?

if you want it to be optional, do this:

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)(/(.*))? index.php?page=$1&params=$3 [L,QSA]

the NC is overkill, and the L might not be desirable, depending on what else you're doing below

Comment: In these rewriteRules the / won't be added to the page parameter, what excactly do you mean?

Comment: You want to get it or you wan't it to default to index? See my updated answer if it does what you want, otherwise please specify.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$    index.php?page=$1&params=$2
```

Or very similar - not got a server at hand to check!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my proposal:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(([^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+)*)/)?$ /index.php?page=$1&params=$3 [L]
```

This is not very nice but exaclty as you requested. It only allows paths of the form:

```
/mypage/
/mypage/param1/value1/
/mypage/param1/value1/param2/value2/
/mypage/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3/
/mypage/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3/param4/value4/
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this already has an accepted answer, but I believe the following will do what you want using only mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1.php?%1 [L]
```

It works because mod_rewrite behaves recursively. That is, after every rewrite, the new URL is processed again.  Each time through, the two values on the end are turned into query parameters and added to the query string.

This will rewrite the following

```
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3/...     --->
/mypage.php?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3&...
```

It stops when there is only one parameter remaining.  It will take the first "parameter" and call the .php file with that name.  There is no limit to the number of param/val pairs.

--
bmb